# Hide image paths like puu.sh does

Tags: image, url

When I look at a puu.sh  source code there is something like this:

```
www.puu.sh/11111
```

and in the source code is

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://puu.sh/11111">
```

Isn't this kind of recursive formulation and there should be an infinite loop?
How does this work?

And when I have something like `www.puu.sh/1111a` and `www.puu.sh/1111A` these can be different images but if these images would be in the same folder these names would override each other.

Can someone tell me how they do this?

Comment: This is an example of 'URL re-writing', the important issue is that the webserver at 'http://puu.sh/' is going to get the full url ("http://puu.sh/11111") delivered to it. It can then process it any way it wants. Here are some guidelines: **[url-rewriting-for-beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)**.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how that site implements it, but one way that you could implement a URL that can retrieve two different objects would be for the server to check the "referer" header.  If its value is "http://puu.sh/11111", then return the image; otherwise, return the web page.

Files with names that differ only in case only collide with each other if the underlying filesystem ignores case.  Case-insensitive filesystems are the norm on Windows, but Unix-like systems usually distinguish between cases in file names.

Note that there's no guarantee that http://puu.sh/11111 refers to a file name at all -- it might be a URL that's interpreted by a server-side script.

Comment: Are there any examples how this trick with the referer header work? Can I fake my referer header to see how puush reacts?

Comment: Your browser will automatically set a referer header.  Depending on what browser you use, you may be able to tell it to never send referer headers (in Firefox, use the Web Developer extension).  Alternately, you can route your requests through a proxy and make whatever changes you want.